# Create an adjacency matrix or list based on shared properties from a data-frame

Tags: r, matrix, graph, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I have a dataframe of repeated items (rows) that in a sense describes items that share some property with each other. I would like to express this relation as a graph.

```
property node
red      A
red      B
red      C
blue     A
blue     D
purple   A
purple   B
```

`A, B` and `C` would be connected with each other since they share the `red` property. `A` and `D` would form a connection since they share the `blue` property. Furthermore, `A` and `B` share a `purple` property. We can weight elements that share more than one property for example, `A` and `B` share a `purple` property in addition to the `red` property.

My question is,  how do I conveniently express this relationship using R and obtain an adjacency matrix or simply a list of edges.

```
matrix <- matrix(0,total_nodes,total_nodes) #initialize a matrix
for (i in property) {
   #some function to fill in the matrix 
}

diag(matrix) <- 0
```

Comment: Could you explain the reason for down vote?

Comment: `crossprod(table(dta))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your data:

```
dta <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
          textConnection("property node
red      A
red      B
red      C
blue     A
blue     D
purple   A
purple   B"))
```

Create edges from your dataset by linking your data to itself on property:

```
library(dplyr)

# Create edges by linking the vertices to eachother using their properties
dta <- full_join(dta, dta, c('property' = 'property')) %>% 
  # We no longer need property -> remove
  select(-property) %>% 
  # Dont allow self-loops
  filter(node.x != node.y) %>% 
  # Aggregate duplicate edges: vertices linked using multiple properties
  group_by(node.x, node.y) %>% 
  summarise(weight = n())
```

Now that we have a data.frame with edges we can create the graph:

```
library(igraph)
# Create graph
g <- graph_from_data_frame(dta, directed = TRUE)
# Create adjacency matrix from graph
M <- as_adjacency_matrix(g, attr = "weight")
```

Another solution  to get the adjacency matrix without using `igraph` would be:

```
library(tidyr)
M2 <- spread(dta, node.y, weight, fill = 0)
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much and in particular for using dplyr verbs!